# Opening text messaging and placing a random array in it

Tags: java, android, text, messaging

Basically my app randomly generates a string when pressed from out of an array. I was wondering is there any way that (if the user selects it) that i can have that string that is generated (when the button is pressed) open their text messaging and place the string in it. So that all they have to do is send it to whom they choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use something like this:

```
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here..."); 
                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```